# Unable to confirmPayment with saved card in react native app with stripe-react-native library

Tags: android, ios, react-native, stripe-payments

unable to confirmPayment when card is already saved and need to payment with saved card details in react native app with stripe-react-native library..

**ConfirmPayment code (Card is already saved and trying to payment with same card details)**

```
const { paymentIntent, error } = await confirmPayment(
            this.state.clientSecret,
            {
                paymentMethodType: 'Card',
               
            },
        );
```

**React native version :**

"react-native": "0.70.6",

**Error:**

{"code": "Failed", "declineCode": null, "localizedMessage": "You must provide paymentMethodType", "message": "card detail not found", "stripeErrorCode": null, "type": null}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a saved Payment Method you need to provide the ID of that payment method when calling the `confirmPayment()` function.

You can see this is the docs for Stripe.js for calling `confirmCardPayment` [here](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment#stripe_confirm_card_payment-data-payment_method).  While this isn't React Native, all the front-end approaches use the same APIs and so much of the details are similar with differences in syntax.

For React Native, the `confirmPayment` function is defined in the SDK reference doc [here](https://stripe.dev/stripe-react-native/api-reference/index.html#confirmPayment).  This definitions shows us that the second argument should be the `PaymentMethod.CreateParams`.  When we look at the [definition](https://stripe.dev/stripe-react-native/api-reference/modules/PaymentMethod.html#CreateParams) for the `CreateParams`, we can see it's a combination of different Payment Method params.  The one that matters here is the `CardParams`, defined [here](https://stripe.dev/stripe-react-native/api-reference/modules/PaymentMethod.html#CardParams).

This parameter has a couple different ways it can be constructed but for your purposes I think the second option is the best fit for what you are trying to do.  It also matches the Stripe.js approach for confirming a payment with a saved Payment Method (shown below):

```js
 {
  paymentMethodType: "Card"; 
  paymentMethodData: { 
    paymentMethodId: string; 
    cvc?: string; 
    billingDetails?: BillingDetails 
  } 
}
```

In this case the only argument for `paymentMethodData` that is required is the `paymentMethodId`.  Providing the `paymentMethodId` will allow you to successfully `confirmPayment()` used the saved card.

Comment: Thanks @RiyanM , Now it worked.  I was just using wrong paymentMethodId.